# Oracle own type overloaded constructors in insert sql

Tags: oracle, types, insert, overloading

I created an own type, with constructor overloading:

```
CREATE TYPE foo_type AS OBJECT(
       foo_type INTEGER,
       foo_number NUMBER(28, 28),
       foo_varchar2 VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),

       CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION foo_type (data NUMBER) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
       CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION foo_type (data VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
)

CREATE TYPE BODY foo_type AS
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION foo_type (data NUMBER) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  IS
  BEGIN
       foo_type := 1;
       foo_number := data;
       return;
  END;

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION foo (data VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  IS
  BEGIN
       foo_type := 2;
       foo_varchar2 := data;
       return;
  END;
END;
```

While I wasn't overload as long as it is works:

```
insert into test_table (field) values ( foo_type(1, 2.2, 'bar') )
```

But when I wrote the constructors it isn't works not at all:

```
insert into test_table (field) values ( foo_type(2.2) )
```

or

```
insert into test_table (field) values ( foo_type('bar') )
```

at this time oracle says: "ORA-06553: too many declarations 'foo_type' match this call"
and thus:

```
insert into test_table (field) values ( foo_type(foo_varchar2 => 'bar') )
```

says: "ORA-009007: missing right parenthesis".

What should I change that it is works?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correct the syntax errors so that the declaration and the body of the object compile

- You cannot have a member variable with the same name as the object type
- The second constructor in your object body needs to be named `foo_type` not `foo`-- constructors always take the name of the object.

leaving me with something like

```
CREATE TYPE foo_type AS OBJECT(
       foo_int INTEGER,
       foo_number NUMBER(28, 28),
       foo_varchar2 VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR),
       CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION foo_type (data NUMBER) RETURN SELF AS RESULT,
       CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION foo_type (data VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
/

 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY foo_type AS
   CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION foo_type (data NUMBER) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
   IS
   BEGIN
        foo_int := 1;
        foo_number := data;
        return;
   END;
   CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION foo_type (data VARCHAR2) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
   IS
   BEGIN
        foo_int := 2;
        foo_varchar2 := data;
        return;
   END;
 END;
```

and if I change to pass in a number that is valid for a `NUMBER(28,28)` column (which 2.2 is not), the overloading works just fine

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1   declare
  2     l_foo foo_type;
  3   begin
  4     l_foo := foo_type( 0.2 );
  5     dbms_output.put_line( l_foo.foo_int );
  6     l_foo := foo_type( 'bar' );
  7     dbms_output.put_line( l_foo.foo_int );
  8*  end;
SQL> /
1
2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

or inserting into a table

```
SQL> create table test_table( foo_column foo_type );

Table created.

SQL> insert into test_table values( foo_type( 0.2 ) );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test_table values( foo_type( 'bar' ) );

1 row created.
```

It seems highly unlikely to me that you would really want `foo_number` to be a `NUMBER(28, 28)` particularly when you try to assign a value of 2.2 in your examples.  If your actual object type were declared like that, your default constructor would have failed.

Comment: Ok, the syntax errors aren't in the real code, but this isn't important.
But my question is:
Can't I pass this to an INSERT INTO statement?

Comment: @user1949713 - Sure, once the syntax errors are fixed.  There isn't much difference from constructing an object in a PL/SQL block and doing so in an `INSERT` statement.  I updated my answer to include the working `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Sorry I was inattentive.. I haven't any questions. Thanks.